# Docker compose error: mapping values are not allowed here in "./docker-compose.yml", line 16, column 18

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have made this docker compose and works all except the minecraft-exporter, the error i get is:

`mapping values are not allowed here in "./docker-compose.yml", line 16, column 18`

I have looked some posts about the same problem but i couldnt find a solution for my problem.

The error is in this lines:

```
  minecraft-exporter:
     image: joshi425/minecraft_exporter
     environment:
       RCON_HOST: 127.0.0.1 \
       RCON_PORT: 25575
       RCON_PASSWORD: password
     ports:
       - 9700:8000
     volumes:
       - /path/to/minecraft/world:/world:ro
```

I would thank some help

Comment: Which line is the 16th one ? `RCON_HOST: 127.0.0.1 \ ` ?

Comment: The line 16 is :

`image: joshi425/minecraft_exporter`

Comment: Maybe you need to provide the tag: `image: joshi425/minecraft_exporter:latest` ?

Comment: I just tried it and doesnt seem to work... now it shows the same error but it is in line 17, so i think it fixed something.

Comment: Why did you add a \ at the end of `RCON_HOST` line? remove it and try again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [yml docker-compose error mapping values are not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959973/yml-docker-compose-error-mapping-values-are-not-allowed-here)

Comment: im still not able to fix it, when i use the yaml checker it throws the exact same error, but there are not tabs on this code so i dont know what to do.... i tried to rewrite it, i removed the / at the end of RCON_HOST but it is still not working, the problem appears to be in the environment, but i dont know what is exactly the problem...

Comment: I did exactly copied your contents and it's been created with no issues. Could you please add your complete `docker-compose` file?

Comment: Thats strange, that part is just the part that doesnt work, when i remove it the docker compose workse, i will edit the post to add the entire code then.

Comment: Here is my code, i am not able to paste it properly on the post:
https://github.com/thejuanvisu/Docker-Compose-Minecraftserver-Prometheus-Graphana/blob/main/docker-compose.yml

Comment: You said The line 16 is `image: joshi425/minecraft_exporter` but I see it's another thing